# jquery tabs are disturbed

Tags: jquery

Whenevr i uncomment the second line then the tabs are not shown.
inform is a simple div placeholder in body

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
//$(#inform).hide();//initialize itto hide-interferes with tab
```

Comment: please post the html involved (and at least a few lines above and below -- more is better)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be because the " " are missing around #inform caussing a javascript error, this parse error will then prevent the first line from being run.

```
$("#inform").hide();
```

Will parse correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean `$("#inform").hide()`.